# How to get calculated fields to work in AOR?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am surprised that this question does not come more often. Forms have calculated fields all the time. I guess that `Redux-form` has some issues with it, so AOR does too.  https://github.com/final-form/final-form already features calculated fields...

While https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input is excellent, and calculations can be made with the resolve, I don't see a way to actually set that value to the the DependentInput source. (All it does now is to unhide when values in item1 and item2 have been entered).

```
import { DependentInput } from 'aor-dependent-input';

const totalcalculated= (record) => record.item1 + record.item2);

export const UserCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <NumberInput source="item1" />
            <NumberInput source="item2" />

            <DependentInput resolve={totalcalculated}>
                <NumberInput source="total" />
            </DependentInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

Comment: What you are actually trying to achieve is not apparent. Can you explain your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace either the `NumberInput` or `SimpleForm` with your own custom component.